# Prove that the solutions for a given differential equation with initial conditions are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I started working on differential equations last week, and i had an exercise where i had to find two solutions for a differential equation(with different initial conditions).
This is the equation: $$y''-3y' + 2y=0$$

So i have found the general solution for this equation, which is : $$ y= \alpha e^{2x} + \beta e^x$$

But the exercise asks me to find $y_1, y_2$ for these different initial conditions:

$\begin{cases}  
y_1(0)=1 \\
y_1'(0)=0
\end{cases}$
$\begin{cases}
y_2(0)=0  & \\
y_2'(0)=1 & 
\end{cases}$

I found both solutions after solving two different systems of linear equations and this was the result:

$y_1 =e^{2x} - 2e^x$,
$y_2=-e^{2x} + e^x$.

The problem comes when the exercise tells me i have to prove these equations $y_1$, $y_2$ are linearly independent in the vectorial space of all real functions $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$

I tried using knowledge i learnt from Linear Algebra:

$y_1,y_2$ are linearly independant if there exist scalars $a_1,a_2$ not all zero that: $a_1y_1 + a_2y_2=0$.

Thus, $$a_1(e^{2x} - 2e^x) + a_2(e^{2x} + e^x)=0$$

We can re-write this as:  $$e^{2x}(a_1 + a_2) + e^x(-2a_1 + a_2)=0$$

if we solve this system :
$\begin{cases}  
a_1 + a_2=0 \\
-2a_1 + a_2=0
\end{cases}$

We can deduce: $a_1 =0=a_2$. Then our functions are linearly independant, and we finished. Was my reasoning right? Is there any mistake?

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Your reasoning is OK.